# Text with two categories at the same time in spaCy

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, spacy

I wanted to know if a text with two categories is possible. Below are two example sentences:

`"I want to eat a pizza" should return the FOOD category.`

`"I want to eat pizza and play football" should return FOOD and SPORT categories.`

One solution I thought of was to train new entities (pizza, apple, football, volleyball, etc) and replace them with the string FOOD_ENT and SPORT_ENT and put them in training like this:

`{"I want to eat a FOOD_ENT and play SPORT_ENT", FOOD: TRUE, SPORT: TRUE}`

`{"I want to eat a FOOD_ENT", FOOD: TRUE, SPORT: FALSE}`

`{"I want to play SPORT_ENT", FOOD: FALSE, SPORT: TRUE}`

However, from what I saw, apparently spaCy does not support phrases with multiple categories, which would lead me to combine the categories: FOOD, SPORT, FOOD_SPORT, FOOD_SPORT_MUSIC, FOOD_MUSIC, MUSIC, SPORT_MUSIC... Something that would be unfeasible and inefficient to do.

I've also thought about instantiating several categorizers (food, sport, etc), each one trained with two YES/NO categories, which is a really bad solution. However, one predicate of the sentence interferes with the other, for example, in "I want to eat a pizza and play football" predicate 1 (I want to eat a pizza) interferes with predicate 2 (play football) and, in the end, none of the categorizers detects correctly.